# Android: Getting the count of items with a specific code in a Room database

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, android-room

I am essentially trying to create some kind of a search feature. I am using a Room database and every element has a specific 3-digit code submitted by the user. However, when I try to get the number of elements with a specific 3-digit code and display it in a Toast message in Main Activity, I always get 0 as a result.

Each entity of my table is an object of a Word class I have created as shown here:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class Word {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word_code")
    private int wordCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
    private String word;

    public Word(int uid, int wordCode, String word){
        this.uid = uid;
        this.wordCode = wordCode;
        this.word = word;
    }
    public int getUid(){
        return uid;
    }
    public int getWordCode(){
        return wordCode;
    }
    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }
}
```

My DAO class looks like this:

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Word word);


    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM word_table WHERE word = :selectedCode")
    LiveData<Integer> getWordWithCode(int selectedCode);


}
```

My class that extends the RoomDatabase looks like this:

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WordDao wordDao();

    private static WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;
    public static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class){
                if (INSTANCE==null){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(sDatabasePopulateCallback)
                    .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private static RoomDatabase.Callback sDatabasePopulateCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new PopulateDatabaseAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
        }
    };
    private static class PopulateDatabaseAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private WordDao mWordDao;
        PopulateDatabaseAsync(WordRoomDatabase db){
            mWordDao = db.wordDao();
        }
        int[] discCodes = {232, 432, 523,233,242,554,221};
        String[] discNames = {"First Word", "Second Word", "Third Word", "Fourth Word", "Fifth Word", "Sixth word", "Seventh Word"};
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for (int i = 0;i < discCodes.length; i++){
                Word newWord = new Word(0, discCodes[i], discNames[i]);
                mWordDao.insert(newWord);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the discCodes and discNames arrays to populate the list as a sample.

This is what my Repository looks like:

```
public class WordRepository {
    private WordDao mWordDao;
    private LiveData<Integer> mCount;

    int thiscount;

    WordRepository(Application application){
        WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mWordDao = db.wordDao();
    }

    public void insert(Word word){
        new insertWordAsync(mWordDao).execute(word);
    }
    private static class insertWordAsync extends AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void>{
        private WordDao mDao;
        insertWordAsync(WordDao dao){
            mDao = dao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Word... words) {
            mDao.insert(words[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getCount(int givenCode){
        return mWordDao.getWordWithCode(givenCode);
    }

}
```

This is the ViewModel class:

```
public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private WordRepository mRepo;

    public WordViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepo = new WordRepository(application);

    }
    public void insert(Word word){
        mRepo.insert(word);
    }


    public LiveData<Integer> getCount(int givenCode){
        return mRepo.getCount(givenCode);
    }
}
```

And finally the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WordViewModel mWordViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel.class);


        mWordViewModel.getCount(242).observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                String toShow = Integer.toString(integer);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in this particular example I am using the code 242 as the base of my search. I first tried using a return type of int instead of LiveData, meaning my DAO Query would like like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM word_table WHERE word = :selectedCode")
    int getWordWithCode(int selectedCode);
```

After some search I figured using LiveData and an Observer is preferable.
However when I run the app, instead of getting 1 in the Toast message, I get 0.

I am new to android development so I apologize for the messy code and for pasting all this code. I have been learning about Room with the Google Codelabs tutorials, so feel free to suggest me any learning resources if having a better understanding of Room will solve my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually searching `word` instead of `wordCode`

Try this code in `WordDao`

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM word_table WHERE word_code = :selectedCode")
LiveData<Integer> getWordWithCode
```